# Linking fails with undefined references to wgl functions of the Windows API for OpenGL in Kotlin

Tags: windows, kotlin, opengl, linker-errors, kotlin-native

When I was trying out OpenGL context-creation with the Windows API and Kotlin, an error occurred when the linking task was executed. I posted the [output of that task on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/M9DUrGgD) (expires in a month) and these two lines of the output stand out:

> ... undefined reference to '__imp_wglCreateContext'
>
> ... undefined reference to '__imp_wglMakeCurrent'

For every [wgl function](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/opengl/wgl-functions) I use, clang (the LLVM compiler frontend) prints such lines. Compiling works fine, but when it comes to linking, the task either fails (Kotlin 1.3.71) or never ends with nothing happening (Kotlin 1.4-M1).

Note that this is not a runtime problem and any other Windows API function works correctly and also that Kotlin provides bindings for the wgl functions.

If all wgl functions get removed, the following code I made compiles and links fine and a blank window gets produced as expected (comment out wgl functions):

```kotlin
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import platform.windows.*

@OptIn(ExperimentalUnsignedTypes::class)
fun main() {
    memScoped {
        val className = "OpenGLLinkErrorDemo"

        // create an instance of the window class
        val wc = cValue<WNDCLASS> {
            lpfnWndProc = staticCFunction { hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam ->
                when (uMsg) {
                    WM_DESTROY.toUInt() -> {
                        PostQuitMessage(0)
                        0
                    }

                    WM_PAINT.toUInt() -> {
                        memScoped {
                            val ps = alloc<PAINTSTRUCT>()
                            val hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, ps.ptr)
                            val brush = alloc<HBRUSH__> {
                                unused = COLOR_WINDOW + 1
                            }

                            FillRect(hdc, ps.rcPaint.ptr, brush.ptr)
                            EndPaint(hwnd, ps.ptr)
                        }
                        0
                    }

                    else -> DefWindowProc!!(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
                }
            }
            hInstance = GetModuleHandle!!(null)
            lpszClassName = className.wcstr.ptr
        }

        // register the window class instance
        RegisterClass!!(wc.ptr)

        val hwnd = CreateWindowEx!!(
            0u, // optional window styles
            className.wcstr.ptr, // window class
            className.wcstr.ptr, // window text
            CS_OWNDC.toUInt(), // window style (this one in particular is needed for OpenGL)

            // size and position
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

            null, // parent window
            null, // menu
            GetModuleHandle!!(null), // instance handle
            null // additional application data
        )
            ?: throw RuntimeException("Failed to create window")

        // create a pixelformat descriptor with opengl compatible settings
        val pfd = alloc<PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR> {
            nSize = sizeOf<PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR>().toUShort()
            nVersion = 1u
            dwFlags = (PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER).toUInt()
            iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA.toUByte()
            cColorBits = 32u
            cRedBits = 0u; cRedShift = 0u; cGreenBits = 0u; cGreenShift = 0u; cBlueBits = 0u; cBlueShift = 0u; cAlphaBits = 0u; cAlphaShift = 0u
            cAccumBits = 0u
            cAccumRedBits = 0u; cAccumGreenBits = 0u; cAccumBlueBits = 0u; cAccumAlphaBits = 0u
            cDepthBits = 24u
            cStencilBits = 8u
            cAuxBuffers = 0u
            iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE.toUByte()
            bReserved = 0u
            dwLayerMask = 0u; dwVisibleMask = 0u; dwDamageMask = 0u
        }

        SetPixelFormat(GetDC(hwnd), ChoosePixelFormat(GetDC(hwnd), pfd.ptr), pfd.ptr)

        // the source of evil. using the function to create an opengl context, but the linker doesn't know the wgl functions
        val openGLContext = wglCreateContext(GetDC(hwnd)) ?: throw RuntimeException("Failed to create OpenGL context")
        wglMakeCurrent(GetDC(hwnd), openGLContext)

        ShowWindow(hwnd, 1)

        // run the message loop
        val msg = alloc<MSG>()
        while (GetMessage!!(msg.ptr, null, 0u, 0u) == 1) {
            TranslateMessage(msg.ptr)
            DispatchMessage!!(msg.ptr)
        }
    }
}
```

So I checked the documentations and of course this requires the OpenGL library to work. But any other OpenGL function from the `platform.opengl32` package works and because Kotlin checks at compilation which libraries are used and includes them automatically, everything should have worked fine. However, clang still didn't like it and couldn't find the implementations for the wgl functions.

Then I searched the internet for any solutions, and a few people had the same output, but their cases weren't entirely like mine and I didn't find anyone who tried OpenGL context-creation with Kotlin at all 
 (I know it might not be the best choice to use a high-level language for something like this and that I could have used another library for what I'm trying to accomplish, but I want to see how much Kotlin is able to do).

Next I checked if the Kotlin issue tracker has something about this already (nope) and the LLVM version Kotlin uses and the LLVM changelogs if they say anything about that (nope, and I know it doesn't make much sense, but you never know), so I figured that the problem must be on my side.

I came up with the following possible causes:

- I am using the wrong version of OpenGL (should be the latest one for my graphics card, I updated my graphics driver)
- I need to do something extra with dependencies
- I am using deprecated API
- I am too dumb
- I am out of luck, and it just doesn't work on my PC

Those are all the things I didn't check yet because I couldn't, so of course I don't know if any them are true. I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of days now, so now I seek help or advice. Maybe someone could try to compile this too. The following script is the necessary build script for gradle:

```kotlin
@file:Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.71"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    mingwX64("openGLErrorDemo") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }

        val main by compilations.getting {
            kotlinOptions {
                freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Put that script in a file called build.gradle.kts, then create the following folder structure next to it:

```
src
    \- openGLErrorDemoMain
        \- kotlin
```

and put a *.kt file in the kotlin folder with the first code shown. Then run the :runReleaseExecutableOpenGLErrorDemo task and see if it compiles and links, then try commenting the wgl function calls out and running it again. This was built using the latest versions of IntelliJ and Gradle.

Of course if anyone knows what the problem is, let me know, or comment if you need more information. And please also tell me what the result of compiling the above code was.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Consider looking through [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/pull/1401) sample of wgl use, maybe this will help. Seems like there is some subtle point in the Windows headers and libraries structure.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Thanks! Soywiz' example did work after I modified it a bit to make it compile for the latest version, but my original code in the other project still doesn't work unfortunately. It still won't link. I even tried to move it to the same project I tested soywiz' example in, but that still wouldn't link. This is very weird behaviour for it to give a linking error and not a compile error. This even seems more like something that would crash at run-time instead of "link-time". I am unsure if that is a bug and if JetBrains should fix something, but thanks anyway, that kind of helped.

Comment: I know nothing about kotlin. But looking at the linker options in the link that Artyom provided I see no `-lopengl32` which is mandatory in any Windows OS version.

Comment: Is `import platform.opengl32.*` missing? Most OGL functions are defined there.

Comment: @Ripi2 No, everything is present (as stated above implicitly). Every other function compiled and linked fine, only the wgl functions didn't. Still, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @MartinTheDragon, I think you should share this problem in the kotlinlang Slack, I know there is a couple of guys playing around K/N & openGL. The only more I can say from my POV - I'm not sure that the implicit `platform.opengl32` will be added correctly on the compilation. IMHO it would be better to add this import.